# Angular displacement and velocity calculation on rocket

Tags: imu, velocity, aviation-electronics

We're building an avionic system which will fly onboard on our rocket. And we have IMUs on our avionic system and we want to get angular displacement and velocity values with integrating gyroscope and accelerometer datas. But as you can guess we have drift problem and we have to solve it to get good quality angular displacement and velocity values.

Our question is how can we make our angular displacement and velocity better and make drift effect our calculation less. Thank you for reading.

Comment: use a 9 dof IMU with a magentometer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine position from gyroscope and accelerometer input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/how-to-determine-position-from-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-input)